# Why am I getting this error? - NoSuchDriverException

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been programming in python for a couple weeks now on my laptop, but I was hoping to run a program using selenium on my pc. I downloaded chromedriver and tried to run it, but I keep getting this error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('google.com')
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py:137, in SeleniumManager.run(args)
    136 stderr = completed_proc.stderr.decode("utf-8").rstrip("\n")
--> 137 output = json.loads(stdout)
    138 result = output["result"]

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\json\__init__.py:346, in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    343 if (cls is None and object_hook is None and
    344         parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    345         parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 346     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    347 if cls is None:

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\json\decoder.py:337, in JSONDecoder.decode(self, s, _w)
    333 """Return the Python representation of ``s`` (a ``str`` instance
    334 containing a JSON document).
    335 
    336 """
--> 337 obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338 end = _w(s, end).end()

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\json\decoder.py:355, in JSONDecoder.raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    354 except StopIteration as err:
--> 355     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356 return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py:38, in DriverFinder.get_path(service, options)
     37 try:
---> 38     path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
     39 except Exception as err:

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py:103, in SeleniumManager.driver_location(self, options)
    101     args.append(value)
--> 103 output = self.run(args)
    105 browser_path = output["browser_path"]

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py:140, in SeleniumManager.run(args)
    139 except Exception as err:
--> 140     raise WebDriverException(f"Unsuccessful command executed: {command}") from err
    142 for item in output["logs"]:

WebDriverException: Message: Unsuccessful command executed: C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\windows\selenium-manager.exe --browser chrome --output json


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

NoSuchDriverException                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[13], line 2
      1 from selenium import webdriver
----> 2 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
      3 driver.get('google.com')

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py:45, in WebDriver.__init__(self, options, service, keep_alive)
     42 service = service if service else Service()
     43 options = options if options else Options()
---> 45 super().__init__(
     46     browser_name=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME["browserName"],
     47     vendor_prefix="goog",
     48     options=options,
     49     service=service,
     50     keep_alive=keep_alive,
     51 )

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py:49, in ChromiumDriver.__init__(self, browser_name, vendor_prefix, options, service, keep_alive)
     37 """Creates a new WebDriver instance of the ChromiumDriver. Starts the
     38 service and then creates new WebDriver instance of ChromiumDriver.
     39 
   (...)
     45  - keep_alive - Whether to configure ChromiumRemoteConnection to use HTTP keep-alive.
     46 """
     47 self.service = service
---> 49 self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
     50 self.service.start()
     52 executor = ChromiumRemoteConnection(
     53     remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url,
     54     browser_name=browser_name,
   (...)
     57     ignore_proxy=options._ignore_local_proxy,
     58 )

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py:41, in DriverFinder.get_path(service, options)
     39 except Exception as err:
     40     msg = f"Unable to obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']} using Selenium Manager."
---> 41     raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err
     43 if path is None or not Path(path).is_file():
     44     raise NoSuchDriverException(f"Unable to locate or obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']}")

NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
```

I've tried different chromedriver versions, but nothing seems to work. When I run the same script on my laptop it runs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

either use ChromeDriverManager or you need to provide chromeDriver path which you have placed locally - like `driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver path')`

I would suggest you to use ChromeDriverManager.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
                          options=options)

driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the chrome driver so you can use those drivers

First use pip install chromedriver-autoinstaller

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
```

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service
import Service Driver=webdriver.chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
Driver.get("website")

I hope this work for you or else check neuralnine yt channel